# get number of used resources in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto, aws-opsworks, boto3

AWS sets the limit on number of resources. I need to figure out the number of used resources for my account using `boto3` and `python` in a script

Is there any way to do this ?

I am beginner in both `boto3` and `python`

For example:
EBS limits which has multiple resources and its limits defined under it.

Comment: What is your particular use-case? That is, what particular situation are you trying to overcome? Do you have a specific metric you'd like to discover?

Comment: @John Rotenstein We need to figure out the number of used resources and compare with the limit to figure out if the limit is reached or not

Answer (score 3):

There is a `DescribeAccountAttributes` call to retrieve some Amazon EC2 limits.

See: [DescribeAccountAttributes documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeAccountAttributes.html)

There are also calls to discover how many current resources are being used (eg return a list of instances, volumes, snapshots).

Comment: DescribeAccountAttributes gives only the limits of the account but not the number of resources used

Comment: Correct. You can discover used resources through calls such as `DescribeInstances` and `DescribeVolumes`.

Answer (score 0):

[AWS Trusted Advisor](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/trustedadvisor/) (available to customers on [Business and Enterprise support](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/)) provides a list of [limits](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws_service_limits.html) and current usage, divided by service and region:

[image: AWS Trusted Advisor limits]

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/awssupport/latest/user/trustedadvisor.html . I referred to this link. Does it has support for python api's ?

Comment: It appears to be supported in Java, but is not listed for `boto` (Python API).

Comment: I tried using this command  `aws support describe-trusted-advisor-checks --language=en` . Getting error `Could not connect to the endpoint URL: "https://support.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/"`. Does this mean i do not have the aws support ?

Comment: I found some api's here `http://boto3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/services/support.html`

Comment: It appears to require the `us-east-1` region, and may also state that "AWS Premium Support Subscription is required to use this service".

Comment: http://boto3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#client . This link gives the info about describe api's which might give the required information.